# How can I write a filetype plugin that evaluates the first lines of the file?

Tags: search, filetype

I'm trying to modify my filetype.vim such that it highlights a unified diff file with diff syntax, overriding whatever syntax is normally associated with the file's extension.

So far, I'm just trying to see if the first line in the file begins with `---`. However, what I have will treat the file as a diff if *any* line begins with `---`.

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *
  \ if search('^---', "n") |
  \   set filetype=diff |
  \ endif
augroup END
```

I've tried various combinations of setting the cursor position, adding a stop parameter to `search`, but nothing I've tried works.

Comment: Your checks will need to be smarter, since YAML is supposed to start with this same marker.

Comment: Yes, it was just a proof of concept. I'm going to be testing the first three lines, for `---`, `+++` and `@@`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple tweak is to use [`\%^`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#start-of-file) which only matches at the start of the file.

You'll also want to pass `search()` a `'c'` flag, to match at the current cursor position (which should be the start of the file.)

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *
  \ if search('\%^---', "cn") |
  \   set filetype=diff |
  \ endif
```

Another option would be to use `getline(1)` to get the contents of the first line only and then use `match()` on it.

```
if match(getline(1), '^---') >= 0 | ...
```

You can also use the pattern matching operator [`=~#`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-%3D%7E%23) instead of `match()`. (The `#` at the end makes it case insensitive, which doesn't matter much in this example but it's a good practice to use it explicitly.)

```
if getline(1) =~# '^---' | ...
```

Either should be fine for your use case.

Comment: `getline()` is perfect, because I'm going to want to check the second and third lines too, and I can use the same technique. Excellent. Thank you!

Comment: Could you also use `=~#` with `getline()`? I’ve had some recent difficulty making the pattern-match operator work like I wanted (I don’t remember what exactly) and would be grateful for another set of eyes :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, good point! In fact all cases in the shipped `filetype.vim` use `=~` or `!~`, for example: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/filetype.vim#L1853 Updated the answer to include a `=~#` solution. In my testing, worked right as expected.

Comment: Perfect! What I ended up going with is `if getline(1) =~ '^--- ' && getline(2) =~ '^+++ ' && getline(3) =~ '^@@ '`. Does the job beautifully. Thanks again.